# Solve for $x$/Lambert $W$ Function

Tags: calculus

I'll be straight forward:
Solve for $x$: $x^2=e^x$
I know there is something to do with Lambert $W$ Function, but the square root throws me off.

Comment: Just search for "lambert w function".

Answer (score 2):

First note that there is no real solution to $x^2=e^x$ for $x\ge 0$.  For $x<0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
x^2 = e^x&\implies -x=e^{x/2}\\\\
&\implies -xe^{-x/2}=1\\\\
&\implies (-x/2)e^{-x/2}=\frac12\\\\
&\implies x=-2W(1/2)
\end{align}$$

Thus, we have that the only real-valued solution to $x^2=e^x$ is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=-2W(1/2)\approx -0.703467592983313
 }$$

where we used $W(1/2)\approx 0.351733796491657$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $z = W_i(y)$ is a solution of $z e^z = y$, where $W_i$, $i \in \mathbb Z$, are the branches of the Lambert W function.
$x^2 = e^x$ is equivalent to $x = \pm e^{x/2}$, and thus to $(-x/2) e^{-x/2} = \pm 1/2$.
That is, the solutions to $x^2 = e^x$ are $x = -2 W_i(\pm 1/2)$.
The only case where this is real is $-2 W_0(+1/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Going For no. of distinct real solution, Then Let $$f(x) = e^x-x^2$$

So $f'(x)=e^x-2x$ and $f''(x)=e^x-2$ and $f'''(x)=e^x>0\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

So Using $\bf{IMVT}$ Theorem.

Here $f'''(x)=0$ has no real solution. So $f''(x)=0$ has at most  one real solution

So $f'(x)=0$ has at most $2$ real roots. So $f(x)=0$ has at most $3$ real roots

Now Here $f(x)=e^x-x^2<0$ for $x<-1$ and for $x=-1\;,$ We get $\displaystyle f(-1)=\frac{1}{e}-1<0$

Now for $x=0\;,$ We get $f(0)=1$

and for $x\geq 0\;,$ We get $f(x)=e^x-x^2>0$

So we get only one real root Which lie between $x\in (-1,0)$.